# I'm having a problem with codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, variables, codeigniter-3

When I create pagination without category it works, but with the category, it works with wrong data. With category pagination, it should show the data of a single category. But unfortunately, it shows mixed category data.
These things work fine on the Index function.....
In my index controller...

```
    public function index(){
    
    $this->db->where('post_active',1);
    $rows = $this->db->count_all_results('blogs');
    
    // Pagination Config    
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'blog';
    $config['total_rows'] = $rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['first_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>';
    $config['last_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>';
    $config['next_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>';
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $pageLimit = ($page*$config['per_page']);
    // Init Pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    //meta title, discription, keywords
    $data['meta_title'] = 'Your meta title';
    $data['meta_description'] = 'Your meta description';
    $data['meta_keywords'] = 'Your meta keywords';
    //data
    $data['title'] = 'Latest Posts';
    $data['blogs'] = $this->Blog_model->get_posts(FALSE, $config['per_page'], $pageLimit);
    $data['categories'] = $this->Blog_model->get_categories();
    //view
    $data['main_content'] = 'blog';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

and my model for the index is ...

```
    public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = TRUE, $offset = FALSE){
        if($limit){
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }
        if($slug === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('blogs.post_id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->join('category', 'category.category_name = blogs.category');
            $query = $this->db->get('blogs');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    
        $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs', array('post_slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

It works perfectly.
But when I try this on another function (category) It shows the data count right but shows wrong data in other pagination. Mainly this function is for categories the post data. Here is my controller...

```
    public function category($category_name){
    
    $rows = $this->db->where(['category'=>$category_name])->from("blogs")->count_all_results();
    // Pagination Config
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'blog/category/'.$category_name;
    $config['total_rows'] = $rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['first_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>';
    $config['last_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>';
    $config['next_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>';
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? ($this->uri->segment(4)-1) : 0;
    $pageLimit = ($page*$config['per_page']);
    // Init Pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    
    //meta title, discription, keywords
    $data['meta_title'] = 'Your meta title';
    $data['meta_description'] = 'Your meta description';
    $data['meta_keywords'] = 'Your meta keywords';
    //data
    
    $data['cat'] = $this->Blog_model->get_categories();
    $data['title'] = $category_name;
    $data['categories'] = $this->Blog_model->get_posts_by_category($category_name, FALSE, $config['per_page'], $pageLimit);
    //view
    $data['main_content'] = 'blog_category';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

And the model for this controller is ...

```
    public function get_posts_by_category($category_name, $slug = FALSE, $limit = TRUE, $offset = FALSE){
        if($limit){
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }
        if($slug === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('blogs.post_id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->join('category', 'category.category_name = blogs.category');
            $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    
        $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs', array('category_name' => $category_name,'post_slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function get_posts_by_category()

```
if($slug === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('blogs.post_id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->join('category', 'category.category_name = blogs.category');
            $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

You didn't filter the posts of current category, so it returns mixed categories data. You can update like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('blogs',  array('category_name' => $category_name));
```